# [WKInterfaceController pushControllerWithName:context:]: called from queue other than main. This is not supported and may fail in the future(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, apple-watch, wkinterfacecontroller

Error - [WKInterfaceController pushControllerWithName:context:]: called from queue other than main. This is not supported and may fail in the future.

In my iOS with apple watch, this error is coming when I am trying to push WKInterfaceController.

What I tried -

1. DispatchQueue.main.thread
2. Delay Timer

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
   if message["xyz screen"] == "new screen" {
   popToRootController()
   self.pushController(withName: "new", context: self)
   return }
   }

Comment: First solution should work. Could you show the code?

Comment: if  message["xyz screen"]  == "new screen" {
        popToRootController()
        self.pushController(withName: "new", context: self)
        return
      }

Comment: I already tried dispatchqueue.main

Comment: Could you edit your question with that code, instead of comment? `Dispatch.main.async { code }` should have done the trick...